# Electron: Convert to .exe, problem with .json file (database)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

Hello I am currently making a ToDoList with ElectronJs.

My code is working and everything is running smoothly.
I wanted to test the first version of my app on an .exe file.
To convert I use "**npx electron-packager .**"

So I launch the app, and I land on the login page, so far so good, I enter my details (username + profile picture) and I click on register
(See the image below)

[image]

I have coded the following way; When I click on register, a function writes in a data.json file the data that the user has entered (I remind that with "**npm run start**", everything works correctly)

So I click and I log in the powershell the database before the click and after the click of the button "register", we see that the database has been modified.

Then I log again, but this time if in the app, and we see that the database is empty...

While it should have changed...

[image]

Here is the tree structure of my code:

[image]

Do you have a solution? I don't know how to do...
Thanks

I log the database, and try to put the data.json file in a folder, but same problem

Answer (score 0):

this is due to asar file is not taking any modification on json file.

put --arch=false while packaging the exe.
this is not an appropriate way for that. but works fine.

also, this will not secure our source code. so, if you need the code to be secured, you have to find a way for pushing data in to  json file for asar file format.

this should be healful for you,[click here](https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/asar/functions/asar.extractFile)